# Does Heroku support Thinking Sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I would like to know if [Heroku](http://heroku.com) supports [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) (and its gem [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/))

Comment: Why not just try it out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like Heroku soon will support Sphinx through [Flying-Sphinx](http://flying-sphinx.com/)

Comment: Indeed - with a little bit of luck, I'll be submitting it to Heroku for private beta by the end of this week (it's already gone through alpha testing).

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that the alpha testing was over!

Comment: It's dragged on longer than I'd like, but I'm also impatient ;)

Comment: Great pat, I'll wait for the beta release

Comment: Just for those who come along here now - Flying Sphinx has been publicly released for the last couple of months, and is running smoothly (but of course I'd say that - I run it).

Answer (score 5):

You would need to launch an ec2 instance, and put all the text to search in SimpleDB, or S3, etc then run Sphinx on the EC2. Response would be fast as your heroku app is also on EC2. So the EC2 instance could only handle text searching, with the pretty web site on Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

[nope it doesn't](http://groups.google.com/group/thinking-sphinx/browse_thread/thread/6960487fbaa170df)

you can't actually use most text-based searches in heroku because you won't be able to have a writable directory

Answer (score 0):

Tom solution seems possible... I personally moved to Sunspot Solr to deploy to Heroku more easily through Websolr. I love Sunspot, though I do face occasional weird results, especially that I need to reindex all the time. Websolr does have minor hiccups every now and then, but it's getting better.

Answer (score -1):

Thinking Sphinx is supported on heroku but it costs 12 bucks a month, which sorta sucks.